# HTML page that retrieves data from separate PHP file, and sends back

Tags: php, html

So I've made a website getting multiple data from an MySQL database via PHP.

Having it all in one file (.php) that it is bloated with `print "*html tables, tags with php queries*"`, I can't make updates without risking to break the php, then using a wysiwyg editor I can modify in the  browser the retrieved data to then send it back to the database.

So I want to play around with HTML and PHP as separate file just to see if it helps somehow. What I can't figure out is how to get the html to query the separate PHP file as soon as I browse the page (not using form submit), to get more than one data from the database at once.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, didn't understand.

Comment: Didn't understand, too.

Comment: Just write the php at the top of the HTML, and place data in various locations on the page. Every time you hit the page, the php code will run server-side, and give you the info client-side without an ajax call.

Comment: @TimSPQR you mean I still make it one file, but I separate `<?php ... ?>` parts? That being a good idea, what I can't figure out is the tag in the html that calls a PHP action. I assume it'd need to play with "$something['argument']" but I'm very much in the dark as to what to write.

Comment: Here's a page with a simple example https://sites.google.com/site/timspqr/home/programs/php/php-code-on-html-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multi-line print statements. Inside this print you can use normal html coding and insert php varibles.

```
<?php

$var = "test";

print <<<END
<p><a>Foo</a>
This is a multi-line print with $var
</p>
END;

?>
```

Comment: That is an amazing option. Can I still use double quotes? example: `print "<td><img src=\"" . $row['photo'] . "\" </td><td ><font size=\"5\">Full Name: " . $row['fullname'] . "</font><br>"`, what would it become using `<<<END`?

Comment: you can use normal quoting inside, no need to escape